# Error found when loading /home/[username]/.profile

Tags: boot, 20.04, kubernetes

I’ve been setting up my computer, having not used Ubuntu before, and after restarting it I’m presented with this error.

[image: error]

The mouse is not always visible to click the “ok” button, so I have to turn the computer off and on again several times until there’s a pointer.

I have not edited .profile, but just in case here is it’s contents:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi

export PATH="$HOME/.poetry/bin:$PATH"
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: @Nmath outside of installing software via Ubuntu Software, I've just cloned a git repo, then installed and activated kubernetes.

Comment: I suggest adding more details about exactly what steps you took, since the error references kubernetes